# $f$ is differentiable in $[0,1]$ ,$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)| \le M\lt+\infty $

Tags: calculus

$f$ is differentiable in $[0,1]$ ,$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)| \le M\lt+\infty $
. Prove
$$ \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{f(i/n)}{n}-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le\frac{M}{2n} $$

I tried to write $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ as Riemann sum by partition $[0,1]$ into equal $2n$ parts. And want to use Mean Value Theorem. But I can't get $\frac{1}{2n}$ out of the absolute value. Come to seek some help ... Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Proof**. $\blacktriangleleft$ Rewrite the equation as follows:
\begin{align*}
S_n := \int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm dx - \sum_0^{n-1} \frac {f(j/n)}n
&= \sum_0^{n-1} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f(x) \mathrm dx - \frac {f(j/n)}n\\
&= \sum_0^{n-1} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} (f(x) - f(j/n)) \mathrm dx\\
&= \sum_0^{n-1} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f’(c_j) (x - j/n) \mathrm dx.
\end{align*}

Now by assumption, $-M \leqslant f’(x) \leqslant M$ on $[0,1]$. Since $(x - j/n)$ is always nonnegative on $[j/n, (j+1)/n]$, we have
$$
- M \sum_0^{n-1} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} (x - j/n) \mathrm dx \leqslant S_n \leqslant M \sum_0^{n-1} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} (x-j/n)\mathrm dx.
$$
Since 
$$
\sum_0^{n-1} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} (x - j/n)\mathrm dx = \frac 12 \sum_0^{n-1} \left( \frac {j+1}n - \frac jn\right)^2 = \frac 1{2n},
$$
the desired estimate follows. $\blacktriangleright$

Comment: (+1) All too easy.

Comment: This is so elegant, tks!